# Using if else in python to determine whether or not to perform an operation on another cell in the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

This should be easy for anyone good at coding I am just learning and struggling with syntax. I have a data frame with 9 columns, 2 of these are `'Account Name'`and `'Amount'`I just want to say that if the `'Account Name'` is `'CREDIT CARD'` I want it to divide the value in `'Amount'` by 2.

The data type for `'Account Name'` is object and for `'Amount'` is float 64.

Here is what I have

```
df.loc[df['Account Name'] == 'CREDIT CARD', 'Adjusted Amount'] = df['Amount']/2
```

I know this is creating a new column but I wasn't able to make it work in place either.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, need assign output to same column `Amount`:

```
#thanks Corralien
df.loc[df['Account Name'] == 'CREDIT CARD', 'Amount'] /= 2

#working same like
df.loc[df['Account Name'] == 'CREDIT CARD', 'Amount'] = df['Amount']/2
```

Or if need new column use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Adjusted Amount'] = np.where(df['Account Name'] == 'CREDIT CARD',
                                 df['Amount']/2, 
                                 df['Amount'])
```

Comment: Maybe `df.loc[df['Account Name'] == 'CREDIT CARD', 'Amount'] /= 2`